# drag drop issue in buttons

Tags: ios, drag-and-drop, drag

i have created a few butttons via code

```
    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
{
            UIButton *btn_pin = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100*i,100*i, 20, 20)];
            [btn_pin setBackgroundColor:[self colorFromHexString:@"5DBBAB"]];
            [btn_pin setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[arr_product count]+1] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [btn_pin.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"ProximaNova-Regular" size:10.0]];
            btn_pin.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
            btn_pin.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
            btn_pin.layer.borderColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
            btn_pin.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
            btn_pin.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
            btn_pin.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 0, 0, 0);
            [btn_pin.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor];
            [btn_pin addTarget:self action:@selector(imageMoved:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
            [btn_pin addTarget:self action:@selector(imageMoved:withEvent:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDragInside];

            [img_main addSubview:btn_pin];
            [tbl_product reloadData];
}
```

and now i want to move those buttons aroudn via drag , i have created a drag drop already but how do i get the reference of this button .

Answer (score 0):

in your loop:

```
btn_pin.tag = i;
```

and in imageMoved :

```
UIButton *btn_pin = (UIButton *)sender;
int refIndex = btn_pin.tag;
```